# Meaning of "Mickey the Boob"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "You just listen to what I said. I want to play Mickey the Boob."
>
> "It's good to play Mickey the Boob with you."

*from Money Talks (1972, US) ([IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185509), by/with Funt the creator of Candid Camera docucomedy/docutragedy/documentary) talking to Dominick a knife dealer, [from on Amazon Prime](https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/0FBAC3NFIM9ZC6L2DHVEEGJTKN/ref=atv_sf_stream_prime_sd_mv?autoplay=1) with a/my EPIX Channel free trial.*

The major search engines Google, Bing, and Yahoo do not have any definitional information in English, even though it's been 50 years.

Speaking as an American born American citizen American English speaker (said in as single breath/string like many presidents at a debate would) with an exactly 3.69 GPA High School Diploma, and a year of University (like Mark Zuckerberg), who had both parents speaking legal and engineering English 100% of the time, my best/educated guess is that "Mickey" is the male Mickey Mouse and "Boob" is obviously the female human part, which is then confusing the process because of the male/female dichotomy differentials (which could be the meaning is pejorative and condescending maybe a curse word too?), so the meaning is difficult to define by ear.

[image: "Money Talks" (1972) on Amazon Prime "EPIX Channel" "7-day Free Trial" A.png]

[image: Money Talks" (1972) on Amazon Prime "EPIX Channel" "7-day Free Trial" B.png]

Comment: I don't know that phrase, but "boob" can also mean idiot, rube, etc.

Comment: @DJClayworth Reference BooBoo, Yogi Bear's little sidekick and the British expression "Oops, I made a booboo there" which, I am pretty sure, predates Yogi.

Comment: How in the world do you manage to get a 3.69 GPA incorrectly writing “a exactly”  instead of “an exactly”? :)

Comment: @tchrist O:) Proof: https://imgur.com/a/mT4dCn6 Thank you pushing to edit again with https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/549844/6 addressing the issue you brought to my attention again. I must say that I really thought about correcting the Tense, I just as explained in the Edit Summary/Commit Message really hesitated to vibrate several people's phone's just to change "a" to "an". However I was equally pedantically offended by the glaring typo, the only defense I have is that I know sometimes the Edit Notification triggers a volatile reaction in the Force guarding this community, sadly.

Comment: I came here via [a Law Meta answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1089/35266) that quotes this question almost in its entirety and points out that a well-educated person should know how to use a dictionary. This question’s downvotes are well-deserved.

Comment: I verified that a more relevant definition of “boob” is trivial to find, and in the process found some interesting things: (1) “*Boob* is a word for a woman's breast — it's also a word for an idiot. So if you're staring at a lady's *boobs*, you probably look like a *boob*.” – [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/boob) (2) One definition is “manboob” (*The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, 5th Edition, cited in [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/boob)), a reminder that this body part can exist in males too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context he is likely referring to a male character who is by nature foolish and unfortunate. It would have nothing to do with female anatomy.

From the source below we see what may be the first use of the term *Boob* for an individual.
The character himself was a klutz, and the cartoon would always end up with Boob doing something disastrous in his effort to help.

As for Mickey, the name was in use long before Walt Disney and the mouse. Excellent work by the Disney folks in Google and elsewhere makes this tough to dig up. Many families with the name came to the US from Ireland in several waves. In addition the term "Mic", a mostly pejorative term, was used to refer to the Irish as noted below.

The conversation above may mean only that he wishes to be the generic fool working for his friend.

http://rube-goldberg.com/wiki/characters.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boob_McNutt

https://www.houseofnames.com/mickey-family-crest

http://www.rsdb.org/race/irish

Comment: So the question remaining to investigate, is why did that individual say/slur "Mickey" and not "McNutt" basically, is `McNutt` code for `Mickey` and visa versa? (Thank you for the info, I edited to add a Wikipedia link, I hope it is okay if I wait to "Accept Answer" for additional confirmations first given the sensitive language.)

Comment: I'm asking myself (everyday so far) if I should trust myself to "Accept Answer" given I am the only second opinion then so far. I worry I risk waiting, for another response to back your response, and having the question modified/moderated in the interim into oblivion... versus accepting your answer and at least making the question look acceptable even if I can not fully prove. Is "likely" (as the answerer says to qualify) good enough, or should I feel confident waiting for further confirmation? I appreciate you are the best answer I've got so far, and you did a lot of good work in my opinion.

Comment: Do not feel pressured. I added a few notes because others suggested improvements. It would be good to put an end to the subject. If needed it can be referenced by others in the future. Take care.